# Golang logging JSON in CloudWatch without added Backslashes

Tags: go, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, logrus

Golang vesion: **1.18.3**

Logging libs used:

**"log"**

**"github.com/kdar/logrus-cloudwatchlogs"**

**"github.com/sirupsen/logrus"**

I'm writing a AWS Lambda using Go. It sits behind an AWS APIGateway as a REST API.
I'm trying to log the requests got into it and the responses it sends back.
Let's say the example request payload is:

```
const jsonData = `{"name": "Yomiko","address": {"city": "Tokyo","street": "Shibaura St"},"children":[{"lastName": "Takayashi"}],"isEmployed": false}`
```

When I log it using standard "log" library as below,

```
log.Println("JSON Data: ", jsonData)
```

It's printed nicely in the targeted CloudWatch Stream maintaining the JSON format as below,
[image]
**Image 1:** CloudWatch log with standard "log" library

However, when I used **logrus** with l**ogrus-cloudwatchlogs** as below,

```
    hook, err := logrus_cloudwatchlogs.NewHook(transactionLogGroup, transactionLogStream, sess)
    l := logrus.New()
    l.Hooks.Add(hook)
    l.Out = ioutil.Discard
    l.Formatter = &logrus.JSONFormatter{}
    l.Println("JSON Data: ", jsonData)
```

It adds backslashes as shown below and loses the nice JSON Format,

[image]
**Image 2:** CloudWatch log with "logrus" library

My question for you good people is,

How can I persevere the nice JSON format as shown in **Image 1** when I use the "logrus" library? Please note that using standard "log" library is not an option here.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using cloudwatch's formatter option? - https://github.com/kdar/logrus-cloudwatchlogs/blob/facbc54742f0fe2e2dcc3feca57cd1e01b4f663a/examples/basic/basic.go#L32

Comment: @Inian
l.Formatter = logrus_cloudwatchlogs.NewProdFormatter()
gives the same result